# Model instances values not updating on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model

I'm building a blog app on rails, so i created a method to update the number of posts when a new post is added by a certain user (user and post are my models).

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes

  after_save :update_user_counter

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 }
  validates :comments_counter, :likes_counter, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

  after_initialize do |post|
    post.comments_counter = 0
    post.likes_counter = 0
  end

  def update_user_counter
    author.increment!(:posts_counter)
  end

  def recent_5_comments
    comments.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
  end
  
  private :update_user_counter
end
```

I test the method using rails console as follows

1. I start to review the previously created user posts_counter values you can see they start in 0

[image]

2. I create a variable to store the first user using User.find(1)
3. I create a new post to that user

[image]

4.When runing the last step the posts_counter gets updated and shows 1 when variable is called

[image]

5.But when running User.all the value is again 0

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I need to be able to see the changes when i run User.all I have tried changing my method but it seems it does not change anything, I'm sorry for the extension of the question I'm starting learning rails and this is frustrating.

Comment: Your code looks fine and since you are using `increment!` instead of `increment`, it should save the update to DB as well. Can you check if `User.all.reload` also returning old data?

Comment: I think don't need of that field and that methods just simply use current_user.posts.count? any specific reason for using extra field for that?

Comment: I have tried whit that but for some reason it just happen the same, it does not update the DB